# is there a difference between ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and delegate BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I need efficient (using fewest threads possible) asynchronous way of doing computation (and I use .net 4).
One way is to

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(f => job.DoWork()); 
job.Completed += (a, b) => {...} //Completed is event I fire when work is done
```

The other possibility is to implement async method as is [done](http://rextester.com/discussion/DTHT42786/Creating-async-methods-in-C-prior-to-version-5-0) prior to C# v.5, which is basically calling `BeginInvoke` on a delegate.

My question is: is there a difference between these two other than different syntax, as it seems `BeginInvoke` is also using a new thread from `ThreadPool`?

As an aside: is it possible to define and call a method asynchronously on the same thread as the caller (as is done in javascript) (in any version of C#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Delegate.BeginInvoke` puts that method at the `ThreadPool`. The advantage of `BeginInvoke` is that you can use the  `IAsyncResult`, which can be used to monitor the progress of the asynchronous call. Its 'brother' method, `EndInvoke`, retrieves the results of the asynchronous call. It can be called any time after `BeginInvoke`. If the asynchronous call has not completed, `EndInvoke` blocks the calling thread until it completes.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's no better answer than to recommend you to read Joseph Albahari's (partially free) book about [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

> [Asynchronous delegates](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Asynchronous_delegates)
>
> ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem doesn’t provide an easy mechanism for
>   getting return values back from a thread after it has finished
>   executing. Asynchronous delegate invocations (asynchronous delegates
>   for short) solve this, allowing any number of typed arguments to be
>   passed in both directions. Furthermore, unhandled exceptions on
>   asynchronous delegates are conveniently rethrown on the original
>   thread (or more accurately, the thread that calls EndInvoke), and so
>   they don’t need explicit handling.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and the [Task class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx). The Task Parallel Library (TPL) offers parallel execution of loops, and the Task class allows you some control in which thread a task should execute, which is important for UI operations.